# Composed machine learning output

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret, predict

I hope the question  is correctly stated.
Here is the complete dataset https://github.com/Maurizio-Mario/Bike_sharing/blob/master/raw%20data.xlsx

The Excel workbook is composed by three sheets: "Note" is the coodebook, "All data" is the main dataset, "Testing" is a second and smaller dataset.

```
library(XLConnect)
work_book <- loadWorkbook("raw data.xlsx")
note <- readWorksheet(work_book, sheet = "Note")
all_data <- readWorksheet(work_book, sheet = "All data")
testing <- readWorksheet(work_book, sheet = "Testing")
```

And here a sample of the data from the sheet `All_data`:

```
datetime            Weekday season  Holiday Workingday  weather Temp    Feel-like  temp Humidity    Windspeed   Casual renter   Registered renter   Total renter
01/01/2011 00:00    6   1   0   0   1   9.84    14.395  81  0   3   13  16
01/01/2011 01:00    6   1   0   0   1   9.02    13.635  80  0   8   32  40
01/01/2011 02:00    6   1   0   0   1   9.02    13.635  80  0   5   27  32
01/01/2011 03:00    6   1   0   0   1   9.84    14.395  75  0   3   10  13
01/01/2011 04:00    6   1   0   0   1   9.84    14.395  75  0   0   1   1
01/01/2011 05:00    6   1   0   0   2   9.84    12.88   75  6.0032  0   11
01/01/2011 06:00    6   1   0   0   1   9.02    13.635  80  0   2   0   2
```

We talk about hourly observations of the number of bikes rented according to the conditions recorded in the variables. Overall, we have more than 17000 observation from January 1st 2011 to December 31st 2012.

I have to predict the daily amount of bike that could be possibly be rented during January 2013.

I will split the data in a `train` and in a `test` dataset to train an algorithm able to predict the `total.renter`variable. I should use the algorithm to predict the number of renter on the `testing` dataset.

```
library(caret)
set.seed(1234)
in_train <- createDataPartition(y = all_data$Total.renter,
                            p = 0.75,
                            list = FALSE)

train <- all_data[in_train, ]
test <- all_data[-in_train, ]
```

Here an example of the `testing` dataset which data I should predict:

```
datetime    Weekday season  Holiday Workingday  weather Temp    Feel-like temp  Humidity    Windspeed   
01/01/2013 00:00    2   1   1   0   1   13.12   17.43   71.00   0.00    
01/01/2013 01:00    2   1   1   0   1   12.85   16.16   70.67   6.00    
01/01/2013 02:00    2   1   1   0   1   11.75   16.16   77.33   0.00    
01/01/2013 03:00    2   1   1   0   1   11.48   15.91   79.00   0.00
```

With the package `caret` I am developing a predictive model, but here is the problem.

The amount `total.renter` is a sum of `casual.renters` and `registred.renter`

Because of that, I do not know the best way to proceed. Should I predict `total.renter` directly? Or should I predict `casual.renters` and `registred.renter` separately and then sum them?